# outOfMemory when loading images ListView

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I download photos from the Internet. have a site on the same page which has 18 photos (80x60 px ~ 10kb).

so I made ​​a list which loads the new picture (sleduyuschuyuyu page)
the problem is when I load three or more pages, a memory error occurs
the question is how to get rid of?

Now I build an array of bitmaps

```
for (Element titles : title) {
                    if (titles.children().hasClass("btl")){
                    m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    m.put(MyActivity.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, titles.select("a[href]").attr("abs:href"));
                    Picasso p = Picasso.with(MyActivity.context);
                    m.put(MyActivity.ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PHOTO,Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(p.load(titles.select("img").attr("abs:src")).get(),80,60, true) );
                    data.add(m);
                    }
                }
```

and in adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        final Map<String, Object> itemData = datas.get(position*2);

        final Map<String, Object> itemData2 = datas.get(position*2+1);
        Bitmap bitmap2 = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) itemData.get("img");
        if(itemData2!=null)
            bitmap2 = (Bitmap) itemData2.get("img");

        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.ivImage2 = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
        holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        holder.ivImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        holder.ivImage.setTag(position*2);
        holder.ivImage2.setTag(position*2+1);
        holder.ivImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.ivImage2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rowView;
    }
```

I was offered to save images in the cache and load them from there but do not know how to do it.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Use disk cache... This article also has plenty of other useful tips for loading bitmaps
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html#disk-cache

Answer (score 0):

The best way to load iomages is the picasso library at http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

You will read the images by using decoding the images to your desired size....

Convert the image into like this method....
It's used for drawable resources....

```
Bitmap bmap2 = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
     R.drawable.hydrangeas, width, height);  


public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Which the below method for decode by the use of streams....

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(InputStream in,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    in.mark(in.available());
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    in.reset();
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
}
```

Suppose you will get fail in the all method You will try this logic you just need to add this line into your mainfest file...

**You just need to add this line to your manifest file. It will allocate the large memory for your application.**

```
    android:largeHeap="true"
```